# Search for a string in Preview

Tags: preview, search

I use Preview's Command-F (find) to search for C# in the pdf document. However, the result is not for 'C#', but just 'C': I get hundreds of meaningless search results.

How can I get the search result exactly for 'C#' or 'C++' in Preview?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. Searching for a command like `ignore=` will return results like 'IgnoreInterfaceRegex' and commands like `ignore:`. Quoting doesn't make a difference. As an alternative to Preview, try Adobe Reader which works fine.

Comment: It is also impossible to search for a question mark, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not found a way to get Preview to search for characters like `#` or `+`, but **Skim**, an alternative PDF viewer ([homepage here](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/)), is a good replacement/addition to Preview and is able to search more specifically.

I've tested it and found it was able to find `C++` (without needing any quotes/special options) without bringing up all `C` results.

It was also able to search specifically for accented characters (like `é` or `ö`) — though requires such characters to be accented in the search to find them (i.e. you can't search for `blah` and expect it to match `bläh`, nor vice versa). In Preview, either search will return matches for both accented and unaccented characters.

Answer (score 4):

Enclose the search string in double quotes, as such: "C++". This will filter the search results from the search for "C" so select **Relevance** as your sorting criterion from the gray toolbar that appears. All the pages with occurrences of "C++" will then be presented first.

Comment: The quotes allow you to search for whole words, but the `++` in the search is still entirely ignored. As far as I can tell, the search function in PDFkit will ignore a lot of characters (like '+') and treat accented characters like their non-accented versions (é as e) when searching. This makes it easier for basic searching but harder to find an exact string.

Comment: Actually this might just be a limitation of Preview rather than PDFkit...

Answer (score 1):

You could just open the PDF in Safari. Safari has a more standard approach to searching PDFs -- it looks for exactly what you type. Preview used to behave this way, but somewhere around OS X 10.5, Apple tried to make it smarter, e.g., looking for pages that contain some or all of the words you type, instead of treating your words as a phrase. This new behavior in Preview is much less useful to me, but I don't know any way to turn it off. You can partly get around it by putting quotes around phrases, but I haven't found any way to get Preview to search for symbols, e.g., "C++".

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Chrome's built-in pdf renderer. Enter the `file:///path/to/file.pdf` URL of the file, or bring up the file browser by entering a know directory, like `file:///Users/home` and navigate to the file location.

Comment: Safari doesn't seem to ignore special characters either. And you can also just drag the files on the browsers.

Comment: Yes, DnD seems to work just fine, thanks for pointing that out.