# Can I search for a multi-word expression in Preview?

Tags: macos, preview, search

What can I do to search for a multi-word expression such as "little bug" in Preview? I want to return only words together and in that order. My first reflex was to try double quotes, but it looks like Preview is searching for them instead of ignoring them. Some googling turned up [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/search-for-a-string-in-preview) where someone mentions the double quoting working as of 2010. I'm running 10.7.5 and Preview 5.5. Is this a relatively new "bug" in Preview? I find it weird that I haven't noticed it before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, of course, it was a problem with me. The search results only appear after having typed the whole query and pressed enter, which is a different behavior than the single word search where the results are updated as you type.

Somebody had a similar problem [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=712783).