# How to escape square brackets in Preview search?

Tags: preview, search

I need to search for a citation in a PDF document opened with Preview. The citations are in the form `[42]` and if I enter `[42]`, Preview search interprets it as a character class in a regex, so I get matches for `4` and `2` as well.

I understand that I can just search for `42` instead, but that returns several unwanted matches as well.

How do I escape the square brackets and have Preview interpret `[` and `]` literally?

Comment: Hi @NikhilKumar - does this answer provide an idea - [use double quotes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/3916/) - that works?

Comment: @MrR I did try that before and got the same result. Thanks for the suggestion, though.